# Sequence of Continuous Functions

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

Does the sequence ${x_n}=x^n$ show that continuous functions need not have a limit function that is continuous?

Answer (score 3):

On $[0,1)$, $x^n \rightarrow 0$.  However, $1^n = 1$.  And for $x>1$, $x^n \rightarrow \infty$.  Clearly, this limit is not continuous at $1$.